# Fulltext index's function Contains(JsonColumn, anyValue) stops working after inserting bulk(25k rows at a time) couple of times in SQL server

Tags: json, sql-server

**Below is the code for creating table-**

```
create table PipeRunTest(
  ID nvarchar(50) not null primary key,
  JsonData nvarchar(max)
  constraint PipeRunTest_CK check(isjson(JsonData) =1)
)
```

**Creating FullText search index-**

```
create fulltext catalog jsonFullTextCatalog

create fulltext index on PipeRunTest(JsonData) key index PK__PipeRunT__3214EC27F8F0771F on jsonTextCatalog
```

**This is how I'm inserting data-**

```
insert into PipeRunTest(ID,JsonData) values(NEWID(), 'Jsontext')
```

**Using contains to retrieve data-**

```
select * from PipeRunTest where contains(JsonData, 'PipeRun')
```

**Problem:**

The `contains()` function does not return the data correctly. Either it does not return any rows or the number of rows are less compared to the original number of rows (checked by using `Json_Value()` method). It does not return rows inserted immediately. It takes time to update in table I guess? And so does not return if searched immediately.

Comment: What "stops working" exactly? MSSQL? Have you checked the process list (`sp_who 'active'`)? If you are adding all of this sizeable string data and then doing string comparisons on it, is it not unreasonable for it to take a while to complete?

Comment: Contains() method does not return the data correctly. Either it does not return any rows or no. of rows are less as compared to original no. of rows(checked by using Json_Value() method). It does not return rows inserted immediately. it takes time to update in table I guess, so does not return if searched immediately.

Comment: That is all vital information that needs to be added to your question and if I may be honest, you should have added to begin with. I highly suggest you edit your post and add it, as it is unlikely people will dig through the comments to find it.

Comment: Thanks Robbpriestley for your suggestion, I've edited my question with required info.

Comment: Are you running your `select` query before your script that is performing the `insert`s has finished executing?

Comment: I am executing select query after insert is finished.....I've checked if data got inserted properly using Json_Value() method....

Comment: OK, let's turn our focus to why `contains()` is not working. Can you post a sample JSON string where `contains()` is returning false for the value of `PipeRun` and yet `PipeRun` is in the string?